# wstring_converter exception when parsing a c-string

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, wstring

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

    const char val[] = "+3°C";
    wstring text = converter.from_bytes(val);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the method `converter.from_bytes` throws an exception. Why? How should I parse the given string?

The exception is of type `std::range_error` with the message

> bad conversion

[image]

The problem is related to the character '°', since if I remove this character the conversion works fine.

Comment: What exception? Why would you not tell us? :(

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23923c288ed5f9f3).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does not work for me, please see my edit. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Much better; now just add the details of your compilation environment into the question, please. :)

Comment: You have non-ASCII characters in your source file. This is non-standard. You are at a mercy of your compiler vendor. If you are using MSVC you better do [what MS is telling you to](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/888437).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the string literal `"+3°C"` is not UTF-8 encoded because your IDE is using a different source character set.

You can only embed the character `°` directly into the source code if the source file itself is UTF-8 encoded. If it's using some Windows codepage that represents `°` differently then it probably embeds one or more bytes into the string which are not valid UTF-8 characters,  so the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 fails.

It works fine in a live demo such as http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23923c288ed5f9f3 because that runs on a different OS where the compiler assumes source files use UTF-8 by default (which is standard for GNU/Linux and other platforms with saner handling of non-ASCII text).

Try replacing it with a UTF-8 literal `u8"+3\u2103"` (using the universal character name for the [DEGREES CELSIUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2103/index.htm) character) or `u8"+3\u00B0C"` (using the universal character name for the [DEGREE SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b0/index.htm) character and then a capital C).

That tells the compiler that you want a string containing the UTF-8 representation of exactly those Unicode characters, independent of the encoding of the source file itself.